# Connect two subnets so that they can see each other

Tags: networking, iptables

I've got 3 machines (virtual) : A client, a server, and a destination. (All running ubuntu 14.04).

The client and server are interconnected via a subnet, and have the ips 10.10.100.4 and 10.10.100.2 respectively.

The destination and server are interconnected via a different subnet, and have the ips 10.10.102.3 and 10.10.102.2 respectively.

I want to ping 10.10.100.4 from 10.10.102.3, and for this purpose I turned on packet forwarding on the server by editing `/etc/sysctl.conf` and uncommenting

> net.ipv4.ip_forward=1

However, the ping still cannot reach.
To summarize, my machines are as follows:

```
Client
eth0 : 10.0.2.15   (Connects to the host machine)
eth1 : 10.10.100.4 (Connects to the subnet 'cts')

Server:
eth0 : 10.0.2.15   (Connects to the host machine)
eth1 : 10.10.102.2 (Connects to the subnet 'dts')
eth2 : 10.10.100.2 (Connects to the subnet 'cts')

Destination:
eth0 : 10.0.2.15   (Connects to the host machine)
eth1 : 10.10.102.3 (Connects to the subnet 'dts')
```

I want to ping from client to destination.

Answer (score 0):

The machine you call "server" must act as a **router** if you want communication between your 2 networks.

You will find all the required information in the manual of the **route** command:

> man route

Basically, you need something like:

- on the "Destination":

> route add -net 10.10.100.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 10.10.102.2

- on the "Client":

> route add -net 10.10.102.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 10.10.100.2

The router should already have the 2 required routes, which are trivial.

Also check the netmasks are correctly configured on all the interfaces (on all machines): it must be 255.255.255.0 (or /24)